Is it true that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(x,f)]=\deg_y(f)$?
Let $f=f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $\deg_y(f), \deg_x(f) \geq 2$.
Since $f$ and $x$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$, $R_f$ is of transcendence degree two over $\mathbb{C}$ and hence $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is of transcendence degree zero over $R_f$, so $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is algebraic over $R_f$ and finite dimensional with $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(f,x)]=[\mathbb{C}(f,x,y):\mathbb{C}(f,x)]=[\mathbb{C}(f,x)(y):\mathbb{C}(f,x)] \leq \deg_y(f)$.
Indeed, write $f=a_ny^n+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1y+a_0$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, $0 \leq i \leq n$, $a_n \neq 0$, so $a_ny^n+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1y+a_0-f=0$, which shows that $y$ is a root of $H(t)=a_nt^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1t+a_0-f \in \mathbb{C}[x,f][t]$, hence
$[\mathbb{C}(f,x)(y):\mathbb{C}(f,x)] \leq n=\deg_t(H)=\deg_y(f)$.

Question: Is it true that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(f,x)]=[\mathbb{C}(f,x)(y):\mathbb{C}(f,x)] = n = \deg_y(f)$?
In other words, is $H(t) \in \mathbb{C}[x,f][t]$ the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $\mathbb{C}(f,x)$?

A first attempt of proof: Otherwise, let $G(t) \in \mathbb{C}(x,f)[t]$ have degree $m < n$ and $y$ as a root:
$G(t)=b_mt^m+b_{m-1}t^{m-1}+\cdots+b_1t+b_0$, where $m < n$, $b_j \in \mathbb{C}(x,f)$, $0 \leq j \leq m$, $b_m \neq 0$.
$y$ is a root of $G$, so $0=G(y)=b_my^m+b_{m-1}y^{m-1}+\cdots+b_1y+b_0$.
Since each $b_j \in \mathbb{C}(x,f)$, we can write $b_j=\frac{c_j}{d_j}$, where $0 \neq d_j, c_j \in \mathbb{C}[x,f]$.
We now multiply both sides of $\frac{c_m}{d_m}y^m+\frac{c_{m-1}}{d_{m-1}}y^{m-1}+\cdots+\frac{c_1}{d_1}y+\frac{c_0}{d_0}=0$ by $d:=\prod_{j=0}^{m} d_j$ and obtain:
$\hat{d_m}c_my^m+\hat{d_{m-1}}c_{m-1}y^{m-1}+\cdots+\hat{d_1}c_1y+\hat{d_0}c_0=0$,
where $\hat{d_j}:=\frac{d}{d_j}$, $0 \leq j \leq m$. Clearly, $\hat{d_j} \in \mathbb{C}[x,f]$.
Let $E(t)=\hat{d_m}c_mt^m+\hat{d_{m-1}}c_{m-1}t^{m-1}+\cdots+\hat{d_1}c_1t+\hat{d_0}c_0$.
Obviously, $E(t) \in \mathbb{C}[x,f][t]$.
Now I do not know how to proceed.
A second attempt of proof: Just view $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=k(y)$ and $\mathbb{C}(x,f)=k(f)$, where $k=\mathbb{C}(x)$.
Now it is clear (?) that $[k(y):k(f)]=\deg_y(f)$.
But one has to be careful: If we take $K=\mathbb{C}(x,f)$, then $y$ is not a variable over such $K$. (Three two-variable polynomials are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{C}$).
Any comments are welcome; thank you!

The polynomial $H(t)$ has degree one in the second unknown, namely $f$. Therefore any putative factor... Basically this old answer except now $u=f$ and $g(x)=1$.

@JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much! Nice. You can write your comment as an answer, if you like.

So my question has a positive answer. $H(t)$ is irreducible, hence the minimal polynomial.
